# How to check if Optional is not nil and property is true in one expression?

Tags: swift

Using Swift, I have an `NSStatusItem`, and when I click it, I want to check if an `NSWindow` is visible. If it is, hide it, if it isn't, call a function to show the `NSWindow`.

My NSWindow is a class property in my app delegate, `var window: NSWindow?`. In my method which responds to the clicking of the `NSStatusItem`, I am trying to use Optional Chaining to do the following:

```
if self.window?.visible {
    self.window!.orderOut(self) // or self.window?.orderOut(self), same behavior
}
else {
    displayWindow()
}
```

However, if `window` is *not* `nil`, it goes into the `if` block every time. If `window` *is* `nil`, it goes into the `else` block every time. In other words, this doesn't appear to work. I cannot check if `window` is not `nil` and if `window` is visible in one expression. (I figured this was an obvious place to use Optional Chaining.)

I tried this, just to see what would happen:

```
if self.window!.visible {
    self.window!.orderOut(self)
}
else {
    displayWindow()
}
```

Which works if `window` is *not* `nil`. `window` is hidden at first, so it hits the `else` block and shows the window. The next time the method is called, `window` is visible, so it does the `else` block. And so on. Exactly what I want, **except** I cannot check if `window` is `nil`. If it is `nil`, I get the obvious crash "`fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None`"

The following allows me to check if `window` is `nil`, and then check if it is visible:

```
if let win = self.window {
    if win.visible {
        win.orderOut(self)
    } else {
        displayWindow()
    }
}
else {
    NSLog("self.window == nil")
}
```

However, this is wordy and I really think I should be able to do the first way. Do I really have to do it this third way? Or am I correct in assuming the first case not working is a bug?

EDIT: this way also works:

```
if self.window && self.window!.visible {
    self.window?.orderOut(self)
}
else {
    displayWindow()
}
```

But again, isn't Optional Chaining meant to replace this kind of thing?

Comment: When you use Optional Chaining, the returned value is **always** an Optional. That means `self.window?.visible` returns `Bool?`. And since it always exists when `window` is not `nil`, it will pass the check. What you need is probably `(self.window?.visible)!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

**Cezar's** solution (first comment below) turned out to be much more correct:

```
self.window?.visible == true
```

There is a serious flaw with my solution below. If `self.window` is `nil`, it will try to unwrap `nil` and crash.

--Old Answer--

As mentioned in my comment:

When you use Optional Chaining, the returned value is always an Optional. That means `self.window?.visible` returns `Bool?`. And since it always exists when window is not `nil`, it will pass the check.

This is explained in the Swift book section on Optional Chaining. It makes sense because when you use Optional Chaining, the return value always has a chance to return `nil`, and that doesn't depend on the final value in the "chain".

**Note**: The above is still true, but the following suggestion was terrible :[

<s>So your desired syntax is:</s>

```
(self.window?.visible)!
```

Here's some code for you to paste into a Playground to play with this behavior:

```
import Foundation
class a {
    let t = true;
    let f = false;
}

class b {
    var A:a?
}

let B = b()
B.A = a()

if B.A?.f == true {
    println("true")
}
else {
    println("false") // prints False
}
```

Comment: +1. Another option I thought of is to explicitly compare to `true`, as in `if self.window?.visible == true`. I tested it and it works as expected, so, unless it has some drawback I've failed to see, it boils down to preference.

Comment: @Cezar does it trap when window is 'nil'? If not I'll argue that yours is more readable and clear :)

Comment: @JackWu `(self.window?.visible)!` always evaluates to the same thing. I don't think this works.

Comment: @nickjwallin Is that because its always visible? I'm not too familiar with OSX programming... The code should be correct though since if you paste that playground code above into a playground, you can change `(B.A?.f)!` to `(B.A?.t)!` and it will print `true`.

Comment: @JackWu depending on whether the window is visible or not when you do it, it always evaluates the same, so it could be an OSX thing.

Comment: @nickjwallin Edited answer, mine was seriously flawed :(