# hasPrefix misbehave on Optional String

Tags: swift

Why does the following always print "prefix" which is incorrect but print "no prefix" when String is not optional or implicitly unwrapped optional?

```
var value:String! = "aaa"  // Same incorrect behavior on Optional String as well.
if value?.hasPrefix("bbb") {
    NSLog("prefix")
}
else {
    NSLog("no prefix")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The if statement is checking if the statement returns a value or nil, not if it returns true or false. You can use another if statement to check the value of hasPrefix().

```
var value:String! = "aaa"  // Same incorrect behavior on Optional String as well.
if let hasPrefix = value?.hasPrefix("bbb") {
    if hasPrefix{
        NSLog("prefix")
    }
    else {
        NSLog("no prefix")
    }
}
else {
    NSLog("nil value")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is related (not sure if duplicate) of: [How to check if Optional is not nil and property is true in one expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459771/how-to-check-if-optional-is-not-nil-and-property-is-true-in-one-expression/24461437#comment37894504_24461437)

Summarizing it a bit for your question:

When you use Optional Chaining, the returned value is always an Optional. That means `value?.hasPrefix("bbb")` returns `Bool?` and not `Bool`. Thus, if `value` is not `nil`, `value?.hasPrefix("bbb")` will always not be `nil`, and so it will go into the first case, no matter if its `true` or `false`.

This is explained in the Swift book section on Optional Chaining. It makes sense because when you use Optional Chaining, the return value always has a chance to return `nil`, and that doesn't depend on the final value in the "chain".

Answer (score 0):

You if statement just gives you an optional result because you are calling the "hasPrefix()" on an optional value.

This wouldn't even work in the newer versions of swift and would give the error :

> Value of optional type 'Bool?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!'
>   or '?'?

Refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) for documentation on the same.

Following would give you the required result:

```
if let val = value, val.hasPrefix("bbb") {
    NSLog("prefix")
} else {
    NSLog("no prefix")
}
```